# Stripe testing working on Localhost but not working on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I have been trying to integrate strip payment gateway system. Everything working perfectly fine on localhost. But when i uploaded to the server it does not work. Even the checkout box wont come .
I checked the strip documentation but it doesnt seems be very clear about its application .

Can anyone please tell me how can i fix this issue?

Here is my code

```
/** hidden form **/
        var form= $('#paymentForm');

        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: '<STRIP KEY>',
            image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
            locale: 'auto',
            token: function(token) {
                form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="token">').val(token.id));
                form.submit();
            }
        });


        $('.customButton').on('click', function(e) {
            var price = $(this).data('price')*100;
            var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
            var planId = $(this).attr('data-plan-id');
            var planType = $(this).attr('data-plan-type');
            form.find('#planId').val(planId);
            form.find('#planType').val(planType);

            // Open Checkout with further options:
            handler.open({
                name: 'StripTest',
                description: name,
                amount: price,
                billingAddress:true,
                shippingAddress:false,
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            handler.close();
        });
```

I want to take the billing address of the user too

Comment: Are there any errors in your JS console?

Comment: No, there is no js error in the console

Comment: can you post full code (with html) here. it will be helpful to find wrong in code. This code is not enough to find out bug.

Comment: I am also stuck on this question buddy... any solution yet??

Comment: @Vikrant are you uising stripe javascript library just like me?
If that the case try moving the stripe javascript library just below the jquery and above all other script. 
For my case, other javascript was causing issue. Once i moved the script above it got fixed

Comment: In my case, all working fine. The issue caught and that is operating system is windows server 2008 in which TLS 1.2 is not supported. So need to upgrade to **Windows server 2008 R2** or **windows server 2012**

Comment: If using stripe checkout make syre your server is https/TLS enabled. Can you visit the checkout page by using the server's IP? Or is it the product checkout box (where you enter payment info) that isn't popping up?